# Is there a way to get a reference to the current task's context in an async function in rust?

Tags: rust, async-await

In a rust async function is there any way to get access to the current [Context](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/task/struct.Context.html) without writing an explicit implementation of a `Future`?

Comment: I were looking for the same thing, for the use-case of being able to `poll()` in an async test. (Assert non-readiness). I now found this, that solves at least my own need for the context; https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/macro.poll.html. If this helps your use-case I could turn it into a response to help future people searching.

Answer (score 1):

Before actually answering the question, it is useful to remember what a `Context` is; whenever you are writing an implementation of a `Future` that depends on outside resources (say, I/O), you do not want to busy-wait anything. As a result, you'll most likely have implementations of `Future` where you'll return `Pending` and then wake it up. `Context` (and `Waker`) exist for that purpose.

However, this is what they are: low-level, implementation details. If you are using a `Future` already as opposed to writing a low-level implementation of one, the `Waker` will most likely be contained *somewhere*, but not directly accessible to you.

As a result of this, a `Waker` directly leaking is an implementation detail leak 99.9% of the time and not actually recommended. A `Waker` being used as part of a *bigger* `struct` is perfectly fine, however, but this is where you'll need to implement your own `Future` from scratch. **There is no other valid use case for this**, and in normal terms, you should never need direct access to a `Waker`.

Due to the limitations of the playground, I sadly cannot show you a live example of when it is useful to get this `Waker`; however, such a future setup may be used in such a situation: let's assume we're building the front door of a house. We have a doorbell and a door, and we want to be notified when somebody rings the doorbell. However, we don't want to have to wait at the door for visitors.

We therefore make two objects: a `FrontDoor` and a `Doorbell`, and we give the option to `wire()` the `Doorbell` to connect the two.

```
pub struct FrontDoor {
    doorbell: Arc<RwLock<Doorbell>>
}

impl FrontDoor {
    pub fn new() -> FrontDoor {
        FrontDoor {
            doorbell: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Doorbell {
                waker: None,
                visitor: false
            }))
        }
    }
    pub fn wire(&self) -> Arc<RwLock<Doorbell>> {
        self.doorbell.clone() // We retrieve the bell
    }
}

impl Future for FrontDoor {

    type Output = ();

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context) -> Poll<Self::Output> {
        self.doorbell.read().map(|guard| {
            match guard.visitor {
                true => Poll::Ready(()),
                false => Poll::Pending
            }
        }).unwrap_or(Poll::Pending)
    }
}


pub struct Doorbell {
    waker: Option<Waker>,
    pub visitor: bool
}

impl Doorbell {
    pub fn ring(&mut self) {
        self.visitor = true;
        self.waker.as_ref().map(|waker| waker.wake_by_ref());
    }
}
```

Our `FrontDoor` implements `Future`, which means we can just throw it on an executor of your choice; `waker` is contained in the `Doorbell` object and allows us to "ring" and wake up our future.

Comment: typo alert!
on pull function ```self.doorbell.read()``` read() should be ring(), I think

Comment: @tipografieromonah Incorrect- `self.doorbell` on `FrontDoor` is an `Arc<RwLock<_>>`, so `read()` is the correct call :-)

Comment: IIRC, my use case was that I wanted to poll a Future or a Stream a single time from an async function.